# SqlCE update subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I wrote a query for Sql and now I am trying to make it work with SqlCE. The problem is that it seems the sub query is not supported by SqlCE. Using FROM in an UPDATE statement is also not allowed. I have done quite a bit of research and it seems that this might not be doable in SqlCE. I might have to do a SELECT and then UPDATE each record individually. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE Items2 SET Name = (SELECT Name FROM Items WHERE Items.ID = Items2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server Compact you have to do it in two steps, first the SELCCT and then the UPDATEs